# Add `cacerts` file to all pods in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, configmap, root-certificate, cacerts

Well, my question is really short and hopefully simple? Is it possible to add a `cacerts` file automatically in every pod in a specific Kubernetes cluster?

According to [this article](https://paraspatidar.medium.com/add-self-signed-or-ca-root-certificate-in-kubernetes-pod-ca-root-certificate-store-cb7863cb3f87) it's possible by creating a ConfigMap and add this to the path `/etc/ssl/certs/`. But is it possible to achieve this on a higher level so that all pods in a Kubernetes cluster have this `cacerts` file?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a MutatingAdmissionWebhook for a pod, which adds the folder by default as a volume to each pod. Check out the docs about [MutatingAdmissionWebhooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) and [writing an admission webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#write-an-admission-webhook-server).

This way you add a "service", which mutates the pod config before the scheduler handles it. Check out [this](https://trstringer.com/kubernetes-mutating-webhook/) for a quick example.

Comment: Alright thanks! This looks promising. I'll give it a try :)